# Output semicolon-separated string

Tags: json, bash, export-to-csv, jq

Lets say we have this file:

```
{
  "persons": [
    {
      "friends": 4,
      "phoneNumber": 123456,
      "personID": 11111
    },
    {
      "friends": 2057,
      "phoneNumber": 432100,
      "personID": 22222
    },
    {
      "friends": 50,
      "phoneNumber": 147258,
      "personID": 55555
    }
  ]
}
```

I now want to extract the phone numbers of the persons `11111`, `22222`, `33333`, `44444` and `55555` as a semicolon-separated string:

```
123456;432100;;;147258
```

While running

```
cat persons.txt | jq ".persons[] | select(.personID==<ID>) | .phoneNumber"
```

once for each `<ID>` and glueing the results together with the `;` afterwards works, this is terribly slow, because it has to reload the file for each of the IDs (and other fields I want to extract).

Concatenating it in a single query:

```
 cat persons.txt | jq "(.persons[] | select(.personID==11111) | .phoneNumber), (.persons[] | select(.personID==22222) | .phoneNumber), (.persons[] | select(.personID==33333) | .phoneNumber), (.persons[] | select(.personID==44444) | .phoneNumber), (.persons[] | select(.personID==55555) | .phoneNumber)"
```

This also works, but it gives

```
123456
432100
147258
```

so I do not know which of the fields are missing and how many `;` I have to insert.

Comment: Do you want a single semicolon between the numbers? I see in your question you wrote ´123456;432100;;;147258´ why does this last number have 3 semicolons before it?

Comment: Yes, because I look for `11111`, `22222`, `33333`, `44444`, and `55555`, but `33333` and `44444` do not show up in the file and thus are null-ish. If I had only a single `;`, I could not guarantee that the correct number is in the correct column.

Comment: This is disgusting and not quite what you're asking, but it might inspire some : `. as $input | [11111, 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555][] | (. as $id | $input.persons | map(select(.personID == $id)))` ([jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/qxTDiMmlYY))

Comment: Now this is what you're asking, but even more disgusting : `[. as $input | [11111, 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555][] | . as $id | $input.persons | map(select(.personID == $id)) | map(.phoneNumber) | join("")] | join(";")` ([jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/O4lnH-_tLA)). You should seriously avoid using that, wait for someone that knows `jq` better than I do and will cleanup this mess.

Comment: does the solution have to use jq?

Comment: @MikeKatz45, no, not at all.

Answer (score 3):

With your sample input in input.json, and using jq 1.6 (or a jq with INDEX/2), the following invocation of jq produces the desired output:

```
jq -r --argjson ids '[11111, 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555]' -f tossv.jq input.json
```

assuming tossv.jq contains the program:

```
INDEX(.persons[]; .personID) as $dict
| $ids
| map( $dict[tostring] | .phoneNumber)
| join(";")
```

### Program notes

1. INDEX/2 produces a JSON object that serves as a dictionary. Since JSON keys must be strings, `tostring` must be used in line 3 above.
2. When using `join(";")`, `null` values effectively become empty strings.
3. If your jq does not have INDEX/2, then now might be a good time to upgrade.   Otherwise you can snarf its definition by googling: `jq "def INDEX" builtin.jq`

Comment: If that worked it would be very elegant! Unfortunately I have no chance of upgrading my jq 1.5 to 1.6...

Comment: @Bowi - So why don’t you copy-and-paste the def?

Comment: You mean `def index($i): indices($i) | .[0];` from https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq ?

Comment: @Bowi - No, of course not. For one thing, jq names are case-sensitive. For another, INDEX/2 has arity 2.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I couldn't test if [peak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53160623/6403504) works since I only have jq 1.5. Here's what I came up with yesterday evening:

- For each semicolon, add the following query

  ```
  (\";\" as \$a | \$a)
  ```
- Resulting command (abstract):

  ```
   cat persons.txt | jq "(<1's phone number>), (\";\" as \$a | \$a), 
   (<2's phone number>), (\";\" as \$a | \$a), ..."
  ```
- Resulting command (concrete):

  ```
  cat persons.txt | jq "(.persons[] | select(.personID==11111) | .phoneNumber), (\";\" as \$a | \$a), 
  (.persons[] | select(.personID==22222) | .phoneNumber), (\";\" as \$a | \$a), 
  (.persons[] | select(.personID==33333) | .phoneNumber), (\";\" as \$a | \$a), 
  (.persons[] | select(.personID==44444) | .phoneNumber), (\";\" as \$a | \$a), 
  (.persons[] | select(.personID==55555) | .phoneNumber)"
  ```
- Result:

  ```
  123456
  ";"
  432100
  ";"
  ";"
  ";"
  147258
  ```
- Delete the newlines and `"`:

  ```
  <commandAsAbove> | tr --delete "\n\""
  ```
- Result:

  ```
  123456;432100;;;147258
  ```

Do not get me wrong, this is far uglier than peak's answer, but it worked for me yesterday.

Comment: The last two parts can easily be done by `jq` : to delete the newlines, first put your results in an array then join them with the empty string (`[ command ] | join("")`). This would leave you with a `"1;2;;;3"` result, in which you can remove the quotes by using the `-r` "raw-output" flag. See [this jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/1Q-v03cJ_t).

Comment: Oh and bash-wise : 1) make your life easier by enclosing your jq command in single quotes so you don't have to escape the double-quotes and dollars inside and 2) prefer `jq command file` to `cat file | jq command`

Comment: Also, `E as $a | $a` can here be simplified to just `E` in each case.

Answer (score 0):

Without jq solution:

```
for i in $(seq 11111 11111 55555)
do
  string=$(grep -B1 "$i" persons.txt | head -1 | sed 's/.* \(.*\),/\1/g')
  echo "$string;" >> output
done
cat output | tr -d '\n' | rev | cut -d';' -f2- | rev > tmp && mv tmp output
```

This little script will yield the result you want and you can adapt it quickly if the input data varies

```
cat output
123456;432100;;;147258
```

Comment: Do I see this right -- this relies heavily on the JSON structure being the same every time, correct? Thus, when an entry gets mixed (eg. friends after phone number), it stops working?

Comment: yep this makes the assumption that each JSON "person" will have friends, phone and ID in that order of lines.